# How to remove blue color from hyperlink

Tags: html, css

You can see the blue color on this hyperlink which i have visited. I am trying to remove this but still not able to get idea how to do this.

[image]

```
.myLink:visited,.myLink:hover,.myLink:focus,.myLink:active{
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Consider making a minimal reproducible case so that folks may see for themselves the interactions of the code in place.  Either a snippet here, or jsbin.  Something that let's other recreate the image above in a "live" sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css class

```
outline: none;
border: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its maybe your `outline` or `box-shadow` or `border` when you hover...you have to check that by inspecting the element in the browser...

Use below css to the link:hover.

```
.myLink:visited,.myLink:hover,
.myLink:focus,.myLink:active{
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid such cases, its always better to add css reset so that there is no need to always override the default browser styles, In your case its the default outline applied by the browser.

Check out [this page](https://cssreset.com/scripts/html5-doctor-css-reset-stylesheet/) , it will fix this issue as well as other you might face later.

Answer (score -1):

```
.myLink:visited{
     border:none;
}
```

Comment: code only responses are often not helpful to the user, please include an explanation.